# Upper Limit of the Hubble Parameter right after Inflation

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

When I take the FLRW equation

$$H_{(t)}=H_0\cdot\sqrt{\Omega_R\cdot a_{(t)}^{-4}+\Omega_M\cdot a_{(t)}^{-3}+\Omega_K\cdot a_{(t)}^{-2}+\Omega_{\Lambda}}$$

and calculate the value of the Hubbleparameter with time it goes to Limit Infinity when I go to the Limit of $t\rightarrow 0$.

In reality the Hubbleparameter did of course not start infinitely high. There is said to be a short time of inflation where $H_{(t)}$ had a [high, but constant value](http://yukterez.ist.org/inflation.png), which then quickly fell of when the radiation dominated era took over.

Does anyone know which numerical value $H_{(t)}$ had during inflation, and with which value the radiation dominated era began?

The value of $H_{(t)}$ today is $67150 \text{m}/\text{Mpc}/\text{sec} =2.2\cdot 10^{-18} \, \text{sec}^{-1}$. But how high did it start?

My actual progress is plotted [here](http://yukterez.ist.org/lcdm) and [here](http://yukterez.ist.org/expc.gif) which brings me near to the solutions published by the Planck Team, but the inflation phase is still missing.

(Of course I could try to extrapolate this data from the Log-Plot in Link [1](http://yukterez.ist.org/inflation.png), where we see that the scalefactor was somewhere near $10^{-30}$, but there must be a better and exacter reference than counting the Pixels between $10^{-30}$ and $10^{-20}$ to estimate the rough order of magnitude. Also, since this sketch is older and propably drawn from WMAP data instead of Planck 2013 not very quotable)

Comment: I think the doubling time during inflation is normally taken to be around $10^{-34}$ to $10^{-35}$ seconds, so the Hubble constant would be the inverse of this i.e. $10^{34}$ to $10^{35}$ s$^{-1}$.

Comment: And that would also be the value where the radiation phase blends in, so I would first have to solve for the time/scalefactor when $H_{(t)}$ was $10^{-34} \text{s}^{-1}$ and then use this value constant from there to $a$ and $t$ = $0$?

Comment: You could just do the integration taking $\Lambda$ to be a function of time/scale instead of a constant. The trouble is that we know too little about how inflation worked for the results to be very reliable.

Comment: I would program the function using the Minimum-Function http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html which would look like $H_{(t)}=Min[ H_{Max} \text{ , } \, H_0\cdot\sqrt{\Omega_R\cdot a^{-4}+...}]$ so when the Hubbleparameter gets higher than the specificied value $H_{Max}$ it gets flattened into a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Until *radiation-matter equality* at redshift $z_\mathrm{eq} \simeq 3370$ corresponding to a scale factor $a_\mathrm{eq} \simeq 0.0003$ ([Planck Collaboration et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01589)), the Universe was radiation-dominated, meaning that the scale factor scales with time $t$ like
$a \propto t^{1/2}$. That is
$$
a_\mathrm{rad}(t) = a_\mathrm{eq} \left( \frac{t}{t_\mathrm{eq}} \right)^{1/2},
$$
where $t_\mathrm{eq}$ is the age of the Universe at radiation-matter equality. This age can be calculated to $t_\mathrm{eq} \simeq 52\,\mathrm{kyr}$ by integrating the Friedmann equation with a Planck 2016 cosmology$^\dagger$.

If you assume that inflation ended at $t=10^{-32}\,\mathrm{s}$, then the equation above yields
$$
a_\mathrm{just\,after\,inflation} = 2.3\times10^{-26},
$$
or $z_\mathrm{just\,after\,inflation} = 4.3\times10^{25}$.
Again from the Friedmann equation you then have$^\ddagger$
$$
H(t_\mathrm{just\,after\,inflation}) \sim 10^{51}\,\mathrm{km}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Mpc}^{-1}.
$$

---

$^\dagger$ <sub>In Python: `astropy.cosmology.Planck15.age(3370)`</sub>

$^\ddagger$ <sub>In Python: `astropy.cosmology.Planck15.H(4.3e25)`</sub>