# Time in Universe Chronology - Duration of inflation period

Tags: space-expansion, universe, time-dilation, redshift

When you read articles about the chronology of the Universe, you read for example that the duration of the inflation era is roughly $10^{-32}$s. We also know   Universe expansion causes  a redshift which can be expressed  in terms of ratio of two frequencies. If we imagine  the comparison of ideal clocks between now and then, knowing the redshift, we could evaluate a time dilation between  proper time at the time of inflation, and time measured on our ideal clock today. My question is the following : when one speaks of a duration of $10^{-32}$s for the inflation, are we talking about   proper time, i.e. the time that an hypothetical ideal clock would measure at that moment, or are we speaking of "Cosmological time", that is  time measured today on our own ideal clock?

Let me clarify  the reason for my question. If indeed, inflation ends at about t = $10^{-32}$ s, as indicated in this   [plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg) from Wikipedia, and if this time is measured in our present frame where the clocks are, it means that the duration of inflation, as measured by such clock, has an upper bound of $10^{-32}$s. Therefore, an ideal clock located at inflation time, would measure an even shorter time. Assuming as mentionned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe) that "*Cosmic inflation expands space by a factor of the order of $10^{26}$ over a time of the order of $10^{−33}$ to $10^{−32}$ seconds*", then adding again another expansion factor of $10^{3}$ between decoupling and now, this would imply that the duration of inflation as measured by a "local" clock  at the beginning of inflation, would be less than $10^{-32}*10^{-29}=10^{-61}$ second! (Here I have used  that $1+z=\frac{\nu_E}{\nu_R}=\frac{dt_R}{dt_E}=\frac{a(t_R)}{a(t_E)}$. See Hobson & al., p.368)

I would have figured out that the inflation duration of $10^{-32}$s would have been the proper time duration, and hence that its duration as measured with our current clocks would have been much longer. Not the opposite!

Any explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Our clocks cannot measure the duration of inflation directly, since they weren't there at the time. What we can (in principle, in the case of inflation) measure are the signals coming from past events. And yes, if these signals come from near the Big Bang they are massively redshifted and slowed down by the time they get to us.

But the times discussed in cosmology are pretty much always proper times of objects comoving with the expansion (a.k.a. the *Hubble flow*). So when we say that inflation lasted $10^{-32}\, \mathrm{s}$, that's the time a clock would have measured back then. If we could see it with our own eyes (or an instrument), it would seem to us to have happened much more slowly, thanks to the redshift. In fact, this is exactly what happens with the CMB: radio antennas measure an electric field oscillating around $1.5\times 10^{11}$ times per second. But an observer present when it was emitted would have seen it oscillating a thousand times faster. Same goes for inflation.

Edit: to calculate how much longer inflation looks, a simple approximation would be to consider a time interval much shorter than the duration of inflation. In that case you just multiply by the redshift factor, which is indeed around $10^{26}$.

If you want to see what happens to the whole of inflation then things get a bit more complicated, because the redshift factor changes quickly throughout inflation. We use the basic equation $dr = c\, dt/a(t)$ for light rays and consider a point at some comoving distance $R$ from us which emits light at times $t_{e1}$ and $t_{e2}$ (the beginning and end of inglation), which we receive at times $t_{o1}$ and $t_{o2}$. Integrating both sides of the equation from $t_{e1}$ to $t_{o1}$ and from $t_{e2}$ to $t_{o2}$, we find

$$\int_{t_{e1}}^{t_{o1}} \frac{dt}{a} = \int_{t_{e2}}^{t_{o2}} \frac{dt}{a},$$

which implies

$$\int_{t_{o1}}^{t_{o2}} \frac{dt}{a} = \int_{t_{e1}}^{t_{e2}} \frac{dt}{a}.$$

For the LHS, assume the time difference between the two receptions is shorter than the Hubble time, so we just get $\Delta t_o = t_{o2}-t_{o1}$ (also setting $a(t_0) = 1$). The RHS turns out to be

$$\frac{e^{H \Delta t_e}-1}{a_{BB}H},$$

where $a_{BB}$ is the scale factor at the end of inflation and $H$ is the Hubble parameter during inflation. Plugging in some numbers I found in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/390614/5788) just as an example, I find $\Delta t_o \approx 5\times 10^{-7}\,\mathrm{s}$.

Comment: This seems more realistic to me (see my clarifications to my question). However, usually, in Uniserve time charts, they usually refer to $10^{-32}$ for example,  as a duration measured in Cosmological time, that is time on our clocks if I understand correctly.

Comment: @LOICM Cosmological time 99% of the times means proper time. But there is a deeper misunderstanding here: there is no such thing as measuring times "back then" with our clocks. You can only measure the duration of an event with a clock that is present right there at the event; otherwise, you always use indirect methods, which in most cases just means receiving light signals. And yes, these light signals are redshifted, but cosmologists know they have to correct for that. So again, cosmological times are proper times.

Comment: If you have seen the movie "Insterstellar", you may recall that when the people having spent 1h  on Miller's planet, in Gargantua's strong field,  meet again with the guy left in the shuttle, he is 7 years older. They could anticipate this using Shwarzschild metric. Here  I'd like to do the same using FRLW metric. If then we say that inflation lasted $10^{−32}$s,  "on a clock  back then", do I understand correctly if I say that "If we could see it with our own eyes", we would "see" it lasting much longer, and (using my evaluation),  this much longer would mean at least  $10^{29}$ times longer?

Comment: @LOICM See my edit.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment  @anna v, "To be more precise, in my evaluation of scale factors ratio, I would need to integrated it over the duration of inflation, but I just wanted an upper bound, which is far than enough to illustrate my interrogations." In your edit, you are  just doing that integration, and the correction it brings to my approximation of $10^{-32}*10^{29}=10^{-3}$ is consistent and gives me  all the answers I was looking for.

Comment: Reading again this subject, I still would like to confirm the following: I understand that "times discussed in cosmology are pretty much always proper times of objects comoving with the expansion". Therefore, when we say that the age of the Universe is roughly 13.7 Billion years, do you confirm that this is meant as measured by a clock comoving with the expansion? This would mean that the corresponding duration, "seen" by us would be longer, due to the redshift as explained in your answer. Is this correct? What would be the  impact on the value of the "age of the Universe" evaluated that way?

Comment: @LOICM Yes, the cited age of the universe is comoving. But there is no such thing as the time seen by us; you can't measure time intervals at a different time. That is the key concept here, which I emphasized in the first sentence of my answer. To measure the age of the universe you have to propose an observation, and then work out how redshift affects that observation procedure. And anyway we don't measure the age of the universe, we calculate it based on what we know about its physical evolution.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If I do as in your example above for the duration of inflation, i.e. choose a point at some comoving distance R from us which emits light at times te1 and te2 (for example in this case,  te1=recombination time and te2=apparition of Homo Sapiens on earth, 200 000 years from now, with (te2- te1) then close to 13.7 Billion years ),  which we receive at times to1 and to2. Wouldn’t integrating similarly as what you did, pretty much give us a duration which could be considered as what the age of the universe seems to be for us?

Answer (score 1):

The [Big Bang time line](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) is seen here:

[image: timelineBB]

The time is counted from the calculated big bang point, but it is given by our present frame where the clocks are. The inflationary epoch is seen in this plot to be between about $10^{-38}$ seconds  to $10^{-36}$ seconds.

In [this plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#/media/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg) it is seen that a fuzzy region  is drawn for the original  Big Bang estimate  point singularity .

In t[his article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_and_proper_distances#Uses_of_the_proper_distance)

> The comoving time coordinate is the elapsed time since the Big Bang according to a clock of a comoving observer and is a measure of cosmological time. The comoving spatial coordinates tell where an event occurs while cosmological time tells when an event occurs. Together, they form a complete coordinate system, giving both the location and time of an event.

Comoving time and proper time are two different mathematically numbers, but the timelines of the Big Bang are given in comoving time. This is as far as I have managed to clarify for myself.

Comment: have a look at this, and see that it is not a simple matter https://users.sussex.ac.uk/~waa22/relativity/What_is_gravitational_time_dilation.html .to work proper times for large gravitaionla masses.

Comment: I have added some clarification for the reason of my question, and some estimations based on the redshift based on FRLW metric, which  effect is indeed is even stronger than for Schwarzschild metric. To be more precise, in my evaluation of scale factors ratio,  I  would need to integrated it  over the duration of inflation, but  I just wanted an upper bound, which is far than enough to illustrate my interrogations.